# Is there a safe way for clients to send cached data back to the server?

Tags: javascript, caching, web, server, client

I have a site where some processing is done on the client side in javascript. It works well, but it occurred to me the same thing should not be done over and over again even if it only affects the client, so the processed data could be sent back to the server by a client and later other clients could get that cached data, so they don't have to do the processing themselves.

The problem is there isn't any kind of authentication on the site, it's freely accessible, so a rogue client could send back malicious cached data to the server.

Is there some clever way to make sure the server stores cached data only from my clients? The only thing I could think of is comparing the datas received from the clients and marking a piece of cached data valid only if, say, 10 clients send back the same value. Of course, it's not a perfect solution, but it may protect most attackers.

Is there a better way than this?

Comment: Why you couldn't process this data on the server side and send it to all clients? If the server doesn't use any authentication how will you know that the data is received from a trusted client?

Comment: @alexmac the site uses certain web apis for processing which have no client side limits, but they do have very low server side limits. The site has hundreds of thousands of pages, so doing the processing client side makes sense, because then I don't hit api limits. By doing the same from the server I would hit the limit very quickly, and since the site is updated often, reprocessing of data is also often needed.

Comment: A website without authentication doesn't mean that your own backend should accept requests from 'rogue' clients, if it does you are doing something wrong in your web setup. Also, could you clarify the amount of data that is returned by these external API per request? If it doesn't make sense to keep them in your own database due to storage reason, then let the front end handle that.

Comment: @A__   As the question states the processing is done on the client, so I can't easily check if the data sent back is from my webpage or some rogue script somebody wrote.  The client side data is not huge, it can stay on the client, I'm just wondering if there is a clever way to know it is from my client if it is sent back to the server for caching. The main point is making the clients faster by not redoing the same calculations, so other clients can use results done by previous clients. But for this I need to send the cached data to the server and make sure it is valid data. That's the problem

Comment: If you call the external API within a promise - you can add another promise within the first one to send a PUT request to your DB with the new data - I don't see how that could be tempered with in the client? And if you don't have that much data in these API calls - you should be able to parse that data in the backend to see if they match what you expect?